# How to pipe data from /dev/ttyUSB0 to a python script

Tags: python, serial-port

I can  `sudo cat /dev/ttyUSB0` and data is flowing in the console.

but I cant figure out how to do this in a python script, to consume the data.

I tried

```
sudo python test.py < /dev/ttyUSB0
sudo cat /dev/ttyUSB0 | python test.py
```

where test.py

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    print line
```

It never prints anything, but if i do ls | python test.py it echos the content of ls fine?

What do i need to do in my test.py to read from /dev/ttyUSB0

### update for comments

So when i reboot the pi and cat out without running anything other than what shown here:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo gpsd /dev/ttyUSB0 -F /var/run/gpsd.sock
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo cat /dev/ttyUSB0
$GPGGA,111448.000,5543.1460,N,01229.2541,E,2,08,1.13,19.1,M,41.5,M,0000,0000*5A
$GPGSA,A,3,10,16,18,21,26,20,29,27,,,,,1.42,1.13,0.87*0D
$GPRMC,111448.000,A,5543.1460,N,01229.2541,E,0.37,331.77,270816,,,D*63
$GPVTG,331.77,T,,M,0.37,N,0.68,K,D*33
$GPGGA,111449.000,5543.1462,N,01229.2542,E,2,08,1.13,19.1,M,41.5,M,0000,0000*5A
$GPGSA,A,3,10,16,18,21,26,20,29,27,,,,,1.42,1.13,0.87*0D
$GPRMC,111449.000,A,5543.1462,N,01229.2542,E,0.40,336.35,270816,,,D*62
$GPVTG,336.35,T,,M,0.40,N,0.74,K,D*3F
$GPGGA,111450.000,5543.1463,N,01229.2541,E,2,08,1.13,19.1,M,41.5,M,0000,0000*50
$GPGSA,A,3,10,16,18,21,26,20,29,27,,,,,1.42,1.13,0.87*0D
$GPRMC,111450.000,A,5543.1463,N,01229.2541,E,0.18,42.67,270816,,,D*52
$GPVTG,42.67,T,,M,0.18,N,0.33,K,D*06
$GPGGA,111451.000,5543.1464,N,01229.2542,E,2,08,1.13,19.1,M,41.5,M,0000,0000*55
$GPGSA,A,3,10,16,18,21,26,20,29,27,,,,,1.42,1.13,0.87*0D
$GPGSV,4,1,14,21,66,084,17,16,65,264,18,26,56,199,24,27,41,281,20*74
$GPGSV,4,2,14,20,37,067,14,18,37,138,25,49,26,189,28,10,14,169,21*72
$GPGSV,4,3,14,07,13,335,,29,11,100,16,08,07,282,,13,05,050,*73
$GPGSV,4,4,14,05,04,025,,15,04,080,*72
$GPRMC,111451.000,A,5543.1464,N,01229.2542,E,0.30,7.93,270816,,,D*67
$GPVTG,7.93,T,,M,0.30,N,0.55,K,D*36
```

it all looks nice
then running the python script

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 96, in <module>
    run_program()
  File "test.py", line 85, in run_program
    with serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',9600) as ser:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 260, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 276, in open
    raise SerialException("could not open port %s: %s" % (self._port, msg))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy: '/dev/ttyUSB0'
```

fixed by killing gpsd

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo killall gpsd
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ python test.py
```

on the server i now receive the data, looking good. (i push over socket instead of the print in answer).

```
$GPGGA,111838.000,5543.1488,N,01229.2451,E,2,09,0.94,21.8,M,41.5,M,0000,0000*5A
$GPGSA,A,3,29,10,16,18,21,26,20,27,07,,,,1.60,0.94,1.30*09
$GPRMC,111838.000,A,5543.1488,N,01229.2451,E,0.55,102.49,270816,,,D*65
$GPVTG,102.49,T,,M,0.55,N,1.02,K,D*35
$GPGGA,111839.000,5543.1488,N,01229.2454,E,2,09,0.93,21.8,M,41.5,M,0000,0000*59
$GPGSA,A,3,29,10,16,18,21,26,20,27,07,,,,1.22,0.93,0.79*04
$GPRMC,111839.000,A,5543.1488,N,01229.2454,E,0.56,54.80,270816,,,D*55
$GPVTG,54.80,T,,M,0.56,N,1.05,K,D*06
$GPGGA,111840.000,5543.1489,N,01229.2456,E,2,09,0.93,21.8,M,41.5,M,0000,0000*54
$GPGSA,A,3,29,10,16,18,21,26,20,27,07,,,,1.22,0.93,0.79*04
$GPRMC,111840.000,A,5543.1489,N,01229.2456,E,0.43,12.04,270816,,,D*52
$GPVTG,12.04,T,,M,0.43,N,0.80,K,D*00
$GPGGA,111841.000,5543.1490,N,01229.2457,E,2,09,0.94,21.8,M,41.5,M,0000,0000*5B
$GPGSA,A,3,29,10,16,18,21,26,20,27,07,,,,1.60,0.94,1.30*09
$GPGSV,4,1,14,16,65,260,27,21,64,082,17,26,54,198,30,27,43,282,17*7B
$GPGSV,4,2,14,18,39,137,29,20,36,065,18,49,26,189,28,10,15,168,16*74
$GPGSV,4,3,14,07,13,334,16,29,10,101,15,08,08,283,,13,06,049,*73
$GPGSV,4,4,14,15,05,079,,05,02,025,*73
$GPRMC,111841.000,A,5543.1490,N,01229.2457,E,0.24,252.88,270816,,,D*69
$GPVTG,252.88,T,,M,0.24,N,0.44,K,D*3B
$GPGGA,111842.000,5543.1490,N,01229.2456,E,2,09,0.93,21.8,M,41.5,M,0000,0000*5E
$GPGSA,A,3,29,10,16,18,21,26,20,27,07,,,,1.22,0.93,0.79*04
```

After exiting the python script `sudo cat /dev/ttyUSB0` nothing happens anymore.
Is this because I did not close something correct in python?

Comment: do you want to read serial input in python?

Comment: [Here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12359/how-can-i-monitor-serial-port-traffic) Dump isn't `redirect or open` !

Comment: I wanted a quick way to send the serial input data over the wire to a backend server and came to the conclussion that python was the easiest way to get there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can read the data from usb port/ serial port in python using [pyserial](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial) library

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)

while True:
    data = ser.readline()
    if data:
        print(data)
```

you don't need to redirect serial input to python script via pipe.

Comment: Thanks. I am not a python developer by default, what i prefered with the pipe idea was that I knew I was not doing anything bad with the serial port as i was just piping it in :) Is there anything here I should be aware of? Should i close it again. can errors happen. Is the while true the proper way?

Comment: seems that running this in my python script have broken my serial port or reconfigured it in some way, when doing cat now it is formatting it badly.

Comment: @PoulK.Sørensen could you post the error you are getting.

Comment: thers no error, but after i have run this when i pipe serial to cat i think the encoding changed or something. Some boxes and such. If i just send the data on the wire and read it from the log there is no issue.  The script works, i just think it modified the serial port.

Comment: I could not reproduce it now, see update in question

Comment: `serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy: '/dev/ttyUSB0'` this shows that the `/dev/ttyUSB0` is being used by some other process which in this case is `gpsd`.

Comment: to get co ordinates from gps module I had written this script https://github.com/girish946/python-gps/blob/master/gps.py see if it is useful to you.

Comment: I fixed the could not open by closing gpsd. But it still puzzle me why after i end the python script I cannot pipe ttyusb0 to cat and see the data. First after reboot

Comment: and thanks for the script. my script push data over websocket and then we have a library processing the data when it comes in.